# How Drag and Drop is used to upload a file in Angular 4 using Kendo UI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using Kendo to upload a file and now I want to add a Drag and Drop feature. but in Kendo documents its not given. How can i add Drag and Drop functionality, any example ?

Currently im following this document to upload a file : 
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/model-binding/

Thanks in advance!..

Comment: The `kendo-upload` supports drag'n'drop-upload out of the box, just drag a file over the components area.

Comment: In the link you provide, drag and drop feature is already working.